Homeomorphism between geometric realization of abstract simplicial complex and triangulation of set.
I would like to understand the relation between two different definitions of triangulations. The first one is defined directly within the triangulated space, and the second one is defined via a homeomorphism.
Let $X$ be a topological space.

A geometric triangulation of $X$ is a set $\mathcal{K}$ of simplices that satisfy the following conditions: 1. The set $\mathcal K$ contains the subsimplices of every $S \in \mathcal{K}$, and 2. any non-empty intersection of any two simplices in $\mathcal K$ is a common subsimplex of both.

Here, a simplex is a homeomorphism $\sigma : \Delta^m \rightarrow X$ from the $m$-dimensional standard simplex into the space $X$.

A topological triangulation of $X$ is a homeomorphism from the geometric realization $|\mathcal T|$ of an abstract simplicial complex $\mathcal T$ onto the space $X$.

Recall that the geometric realization is situated in the space $\mathbb R^I$, where $I$ is the index set of vertices, and span simplices between unit vectors of $\mathbb R^I$
However, it is not evident to me which topology is imposed on the geometric realization. I suppose it is some product topology, but which one? In particular, the geometric realization might be within an infinite-dimensional vector space.
Once the topology is determined, how do I show that I have got a homeomorphism?

In the first case simplices are maps, thus you must give definitions of "subsimplices" and "intersection of simplices". What are the sources of the definitions? A textbook?
